# twitter bootstrap modal with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have run into a bit of a problem and a head scratcher, as I'm not sure whether what I want to do is even possible with RoR.

A bit of background info: I have an app with several controllers... and would like to work with 2 of them for this modal example. The first is a users_controller and the other is a recommendations_controller.

Here is what I'm trying to do: In the user index view I have a lists of posts. Each post has a  recommend button. If a user clicks it he/she is sent to the recommendation index page, and can search and find a user he/she would like to share the post with. The reason I have it set up this way is because the Recommendation model creates the recommend relationship.

I would like like it so when the user clicks the recommend button on the User index page, a modal appears (one that accesses the recommendation controller) and the user can search for the user he/she would like to share the post with. Basically, I want to know whether it's possible to access the Recommendation controller via the User controller's index view page.

If it's not, is there a work around? I can post the code I have if it's helpful, but I'm not sure that would help in this case--as I'm trying to see whether it's even possible to do what I'm trying to do.

Thank you!

**More Details:**

recommendations_controller:

```
  def index
    @user = Search.find_users(params[:name], current_profile)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end   
  end
```

index.js.haml (located in the view/recommendations folder)

```
  :plain
    $(#my-modal).show();
```

index.html.haml (located in the view/recommendations folder)

```
  = form_tag post_recommendations_url, :method => "get" do
    = text_field_tag :name, '', :class => "span12", :placeholder => "Please enter the name of the users you would like to share this post with."
    %center
      = submit_tag "Search", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

index.html.haml (located in the view/posts folder)

```
  %a{:href => "#{post_recommendations_path(post)}", :remote => true}
    %i.icon-share.icon-large
    Recommend Post

#my-modal.modal.hide.fade
  .modal-header
    %a.close{"data-dismiss" => "modal"} ×
    %h6 This is a header
  .modal-body
  %p This is where I would like the contents of the index.html.haml file, located in the view/recommendations folder to appear.
```

### **Part 2: Displaying the search results inside the modal/partial**

Matzi, at the moment, a user clicks a link near the post they want to recommend. This link renders the modal with a partial (_recommendation.html.haml) inside of it.

This partial (now inside the modal) contains the search `form_tag` and the code to render all the users that match the search results. Unfortunately, when I try to run a search by entering a name and clicking the search button (again, now located inside of the modal) it takes me to the following url instead of rendering the results inside the modal.

`http://localhost:3000/posts/2/recommendations?utf8=%E2%9C%93&name=Test&commit=Search`

here is what my updated **index.html.haml (located in the view/posts folder)** looks like:

```
= link_to 'Recommend Post', post_recommendations_path(post), :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal"

#my-modal.modal.hide
.modal-header
  %a.close{"data-dismiss" => "modal"} ×
  %h6 
    %i.icon-share.icon-large
    Recommend Post
.modal-body
  #modal-rec-body
    %p *this is where _recommendation.html.haml is rendered*
```

updated **index.js.haml**

```
:plain
  $("#modal-rec-body").html("#{escape_javascript(render('recommendations/recommendation'))}");

  $('#my-modal').modal({
    keyboard: true,
    show: true
  });
```

**_recommendation.html.haml**

```
.span12
  = form_tag post_recommendations_path, :method => "get" do
    = text_field_tag :name, '', :class => "span12", :placeholder => "Please enter the name of the user you would like to share this post with.", :style => "max-width:520px;"
    %center
      = submit_tag "Search", :class => "btn btn-primary", :remote => "true"

- @user.each do |i|
  - unless current_profile == i
    .row-fluid
      .span6
        .row-fluid
          .well{:style => "margin-left:0px;"}
            .row-fluid
              .span2
                =image_tag i.avatar(:bio), :class=> "sidebar_avatar"
              .span6
                %dl{:style => "margin:0px"}
                  %dt
                    %i.icon-user
                    Name
                  %dd= i.name
                  %dt
                    %i.icon-map-marker
                    Location
                  %dd= i.location
              .span4
                - form_for :recommendation do |r|
                  = r.hidden_field :friend_id, :value => i.account.id 
                  = r.submit "Send Recommendation", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

**Problem:** Unfortunately it seems that when I click the submit (search) button inside the modal instead of rendering the results inside the modal it re-directs the browser to the `post_recommendations_path (posts/post.id/recommendations)`. I would like to display the search results inside the modal without having it redirect to the post recommendations path.

As always, thank you so much! I'm extremely grateful for your help--and I've gotten a much better grasp for AJAX thanks to you. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you can do this, but it needs some ajax magic.

First of all, you need to create an action, responding to .js requests, in the recommendation controller. It is done so far in your update. But, your .js is not quite right. The problem is that you render the modal form from the post view, but propably in post controller you dont have the right fields. I recommend the following .js.erb:

```
$("#modal-body").html(<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'recommendations/index')%>);
$("#my-modal").show();
```

This fills the modal with the form. The next step is to do a remote request from this form. Modify your posts/index the following way:

```
  = form_tag post_recommendations_url, :remote => true, :method => "get" do
    = text_field_tag :name, '', :class => "span12", :placeholder => "Please enter the name of the users you would like to share this post with."
    %center
      = submit_tag "Search", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

The difference is the `:remote => true` tag, this sends an ajax request to your controller, so you must prepare for .js and .html response (in case of no JS on client). The .js should hide the modal form, and may refresh the original page, the html may redirect you back to the post.

**Part 2:**
The problem is the :remote part. It needs to be part of the form's definition, not the submit button's. My mistake.

I found [this guide](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/) now, it seems quite good.

I hope it helps! Ask if something is not clear.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response... unfortunately, I'm a little confused  with your solution. I've updated my question to help clarify what I'm asking. I've tried following your approach to the best of my knowledge, but clearly i'm messing something up. Your help is appreciated. Thank you again!

Comment: Okay, see the updated solution. I hope this is better, than the first one. :)

Comment: thanks matzi, unfortunately the js does not execute. It simply redirects to the ../recommendations/id/ url without ever going through js. Should the .js.erb file be located in the recommendations folder or the posts folder? I think it has something to do with the recommendations link... i think it's simply sending it to a predetermined path without calling js even though it's got a :remote => true condition. Your help is very appreciated, thank you again!

Comment: `%a{:href => "#{post_recommendations_path(post)}", :remote => true}` 

It won't work, you should use `link_to 'Recommend post', post_recommendations_path(post), :remote => true`

The remote tag is not the html tag's parameter, it is a tag for link_to, to create an ajax link.

Comment: Matzi, thank you so much... the `link_to` did indeed launch ajax. However, it does not want to show the modal.  I limited `index.js.haml` to have the following: `$(#my-modal).show();` and the modal did not display. When i replaced the code with a basic `  alert('ajax works!');` alert, then the alert worked--so ajax is working, but for some reason, it does not want to load my modal.   Should my modal be in the `index.html.haml (located in the view/posts folder)` ? Matzi, thank you again so much for all of your help... you are a legend!

Comment: You need to use the name in qotation marks. Try using: `$("#my-modal").show();`

Comment: Of course! haha. Matzi, thank you so much for all of your help! It's working brilliantly now! Wouldn't have been able to do it without your help! Thank you!

Comment: Matzi, what if I wanted to update the modal via AJAX and not redirect to the post's page via post_recommendations_url? Meaning what if I wanted the search results to appear in the modal instead of re-routing me to the recommendation page?

Comment: You can refresh anything by ajax. The key is to render the html fragment you want to show into a javascript, which changes the part of the page to the new outlook. It is just like the previous examples. You launch the request (form/link) with the remote tag, and in the answer, you render a js code which updates the page. Something like this: `function(){ $("#to_update").html(<%= render :partial => "path_to/updated_view_partial" %>) }`

Comment: But here is my problem: I'm trying to refresh the index action of the recommendations controller and the `index.js.haml` file is already being used to display the modal. So I have a `link_to` in the posts view which renders the modal (via `index.js.haml` & the `index` action in the recommendations controller), but then I have a `form_tag` which is tied to the same `index.js.haml` file. Does that make sense?

Comment: You must extend your index view to display the search results along with this form. When you first click on the recommendation link, nothing is entered, so no search result is present. Then you enter something, and click the search button, it launchaes an ajax request, and renders the same view (html and js), then displays the new view in the same modal, with the results of the search. Is that what you want? If not, pls extend your original question, it is easier to explain it there.

Comment: Matzi, I have updated the original question. The new info can be found below the 'Part 2' heading. As always, I'm beyond grateful for your help!

Comment: Added the part2. Minor mistake on my side.