# How to call javascript from controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, registration

I have problem: I want to call modal with errors if there are errors in registration or sign in form.

So how to call js from controllers or how I should do this ?

Here is my controller:

```
   def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
     if @user.save
   # Handle a successful save.
     else
   render :js => ('#login').modal('show')
   end
  end
```

Something like this, but in right way.

Comment: What type of language are you using to do that?

Comment: It seems to be Ruby on Rails.
render :js => "('#login').modal('show')"

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's not correct, so it doesn't matter. I want to use this http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals, but I don't know how.

Comment: What about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300064/twitter-bootstrap-modal-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I saw this, but don't know what is haml and hoped, that there is another way, more understandable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are creating and declaring your modal correctly:

HTML:

```
<head>
   <link href="path/to/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="path/to/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="login" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
   <div class="modal-header">             
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">              
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#login').modal({ ... });
```

Rails (not my speciality, mostly going off your example code):

```
def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
   if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render :js => "('#login').modal('show');"
   end
```

**Note that I added double quotes around the `render :js` argument as [specified in the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).